# Problem of new equal symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

**Original:**
[image]

.

When I write `test\e`, the graph is like this:

[image]

how can I solve this problem? help me:(

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\newcommand{\myequalsymbol}{      
\hspace{1.1mm}\tikz[baseline, line width=0.7 pt, line cap=round]{
  \draw (1.1,0.13) -- ++(0.22,0);
  \draw (1.1,0.06) -- ++(0.22,0);
}
\hspace{1.1mm}}
\newcommand{\e}{\myequalsymbol}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[clip mode=individual,
xmin=5, xmax=15, ymin=22, ymax=60,
]
\addplot[domain=4:14]{16.46/3.6*x}; 
\path (6, {16.46/3.6*6}) --  (14, {16.46/3.6*14}) node [at end,anchor=south east,sloped] () {test\e};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use a `pic` to do that. Your drawing as it is does not fit the axis system.

Comment: I understand. How should i fix the code? I typed `tikzpicture` instead of `tikz` but got error . @SebGlav

Comment: You are nesting tikzpictures which is not recommended at all.  The problem is that your equals sign is picking up options from the outer picture which is altering its appearance.  Possibly the best solution here is to put the symbol in a box.

Answer (score 3):

If your symbol is a math relation you should define it with `\mathrel` to have the correct spacing before and after your `=`.

To avoid the nested TikZ picture, you could use a box.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\newbox{\myequalsymbol}
\savebox{\myequalsymbol}{\tikz[baseline, line width=0.7 pt, line cap=round]{
  \draw (1.1,0.13) -- ++(0.22,0);
  \draw (1.1,0.06) -- ++(0.22,0);
}}
\newcommand{\e}{\mathrel{\usebox{\myequalsymbol}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[clip mode=individual,
xmin=5, xmax=15, ymin=22, ymax=60,
]
\addplot[domain=4:14]{16.46/3.6*x}; 
\path (6, {16.46/3.6*6}) --  (14, {16.46/3.6*14}) node [at end,
anchor=south east, sloped, xshift=3pt,
] {$\text{test}\e$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]